# nmcli_dmenu doesn't work

Tags: networkmanager, dmenu

I try to run nmcli_dmenu, here is the error message:

```
Error: Object 'networking' is unknown, try 'nmcli help'.
Usage: nmcli connection { COMMAND | help }
  COMMAND := { list | status | up | down | delete }

  list [id <id> | uuid <id>]
  status [id <id> | uuid <id> | path <path>]
  up id <id> | uuid <id> [iface <iface>] [ap <BSSID>] [--nowait] [--timeout <timeout>]
  down id <id> | uuid <id>
  delete id <id> | uuid <id>

Error: 'con' command 'show' is not valid.
```

Could anyboday tell me what's wrong?

(Ubuntu, xmonad, network-manager)

Comment: There's AFAIK no command called `nmcli_dmenu` in upstream NetworkManager, so you would first need to specify where you got it. If it's from an Ubuntu package, you should file a bug report with Ubuntu.

Comment: It is a package designed to work with dmenu from `https://github.com/firecat53/nmcli-dmenu`

Comment: The `nmcli` syntax isn't entirely stable. So either the code should be updated for the new syntax, or it should use the NetworkManager library instead.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `nmcli` isn't stable. You eather need to get a version of *nmcli-dmenu* supporting your version of NetworkManager, get a version of NetworkManager supported by your version of *nmcli-dmenu*, or even better get *nmcli-dmenu* switched to a stable interface like the libnm library or the D-Bus API.

From the message it looks like `nmcli networking` doesn't work in your version of NetworkManager. But it works in mine which is 1.0.0 and it works in git master

```
$ nmcli networking
enabled
```

So I would guess you have a new version of *nmcli-dmenu* but an older, not supported, version of NetworkManager.